# Formatting with JS - input_start.map is not a function

Tags: javascript

Im working on a function to format dates, this is how far I got:

```
            const options = { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' };
            task_start_date = task_start.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', options);
            task_end_date = task_end.toLocaleDateString('de-DE', options);

            console.log(task_start_date); /* 31.01.2001 */
            console.log(task_end_date); /* 01.02.2001 */

            /* Must be YYYY-MM-DD */
            const input_start = task_start_date;
            const format_start = input_start.map((str) => {
            const [date, month, year] = str.split(".");
            return `${year}-${month}-${date}`; 
          });
            const input_end = task_end_date;
            const format_end = task_end_date.map((str) => {
            const [date, month, year] = str.split(".");
            return `${year}-${month}-${date}`;   
          });
```

I get `input_start.map is not a function`

---

Thank you for any help

Comment: Why is `task_start_date` an array?

Comment: Please update the `console.log` value as well

Comment: `toLocaleDateString` returns a string, but your `console.log` logs an array, what I'm saying is update the code in your question to what `console.log` currently logs.

Comment: I get: `31.01.2001` and `01.02.2001`

Comment: Okay, so you don't need to map anymore since `task_start_date` is now a string. So just split the string using `.` as a separator

Comment: I get `31.01.2001` but it should be `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: I'll post my solution as an answer now

Comment: I think it was just a problem of different data types, in your previous code, you were working with arrays. Array.map returns an array. So you may still have gotten the correct date format but as a value in an array  `['2001-01-31']` not as a string `2001-01-31`

Comment: You can use moment js for like below one.

    moment('31.01.2001', 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')

Comment: why should I use an external library if it can be done with 8 lines of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to map over `input_start` because `input_start` is a string. What you should have is

```
const options = { year: "numeric", month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit" };
const task_start_date = task_start.toLocaleDateString("de-DE", options);
const task_end_date = task_end.toLocaleDateString("de-DE", options);

console.log(task_start_date); /* 31.01.2001 */
console.log(task_end_date); /* 01.02.2001 */

/* Must be YYYY-MM-DD */
const [startDate, startMonth, startYear] = task_start_date.split(".");
const input_start = `${startYear}-${startMonth}-${startDate}`;

console.log(input_start); // 2001-01-31
```

Comment: Hey there, can you upvote my question so that I can post a new one? Maybe you know an answer to that one too